# How to convert generated HTML Extent Report to PDF

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, nunit

Hi Guys I have requirement to convert Generate HTML Extent Report To PDF.

I am using are C# with Nunit and for reports Extent Reports

Comment: Please add the code what yo tried so far to help you better. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SathishGuru I did not try yet, I was looking if there was any one who has done it and is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

One option to consider in order to accomplish what you need is utilizing jsPDF.  As you can pass your dynamic c# content to it, it is very easy to use and implement.  I have used it in both c# and php projects.

http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/examples/basic.html

another resource:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf